# Delete Query executing regardless of WHERE Clause condition

Tags: plugin-development

I have a delete query that runs when it should not, the WHERE clause condition requires that the query runs once every 600 seconds(ten minutes) since the last database update:

```
$delete = $wpdb->query( 
        $wpdb->prepare( 
            "
            DELETE FROM wp_counter_cookies
            WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(visit) >= %d
            ",
                600 
            )
    );
```

If I run the query from my script in quick succession within Wordpress, it still executes regardless of the WHERE clause specification.

When I run this PHP script outside the WordPress environment, it behaves as expected.

What may be wrong in my syntax?

Comment: obviously it depends on what you have in `visit` I don't actually see anything wordpress specific here that might have any impact

Comment: +1 @MarkKaplun, you were absolutely right in your comment. My WordPress install time setting was late by one hour, so all my database entries were expiring as soon as created. I corrected this by changing the time settings and now all is well.

Comment: @Terungwa Please add this as an answer (yes, you can answer your own question :)), so that this doesn't come up in our unanswered lists. After 48 hours you will then also be able to 'accept' your answer by clicking the check mark on the left of it. Thanks! And welcome to WPSE

Answer (score 0):

My WordPress install time setting was late by one hour, so all my database entries were expiring as soon as created. I corrected this by changing the time settings and now all is well

Comment: this is because `current_time` is a locale relative function. therefor comparing to `NOW()` was comparing two different values. Im most cases it is better to just store `time()` in the DB and save the conversion overhead and be sure that you calculate time in exactly the same way all the time